# System.InvalidOperationException: There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first

Tags: sql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, sqldatareader

I'm getting this error when calling the following block of code below. Everything I have seen related to this error on SO is due to people calling the `using` block, which I am not, but there could be some code behind the scenes I'm not aware of getting duplicated? I'm also not sure how to find what connection is being duplicated here. Anyone with some expertise able to assist on this issue? My stack trace is below as well.

**if (await _userManager.IsInRoleAsync(user, role.Name))**

```cs
public class UserRolesModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;
        private readonly SignInManager<IdentityUser> _signInManager;
        private readonly RoleManager<IdentityRole> _roleManager;
        private readonly IAdminView _adminView;

        public UserRolesModel(UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager,
            SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager,
            RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager,
            IAdminView adminView)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _signInManager = signInManager;
            _roleManager = roleManager;
            _adminView = adminView;
        }

        public EmployeeDto Employee { get; set; }

        public ManageUserRolesDto UserRoles { get; set; }
        public async Task OnGetAsync(string userId)
        {
            var userRoleList = new List<UserRolesDto>();
            var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);
            foreach (var role in _roleManager.Roles)
            {
                var userRolesDto = new UserRolesDto()
                {
                    RoleName = role.Name
                };
                
                if (await _userManager.IsInRoleAsync(user, role.Name))
                {
                    userRolesDto.Selected = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    userRolesDto.Selected = false;
                }
                userRoleList.Add(userRolesDto);
            }

            UserRoles = new ManageUserRolesDto()
            {
                UserId = userId,
                UserRoles = userRoleList
            };

            var employeeData = await _adminView.GetEmployeeDataByAspId(userId);

            var viewModel = new EmployeeViewDto
            {
                Employee = employeeData
            };
            
            Employee = new EmployeeDto
            {
                EmployeeAspId = employeeData.AspUserId,
                EmployeeViewDto = viewModel
            };


        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string id, ManageUserRolesDto userRoles)
        {
            var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(id);
            var roles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);
            var result = await _userManager.RemoveFromRolesAsync(user, roles);
            result = await _userManager.AddToRolesAsync(user, userRoles.UserRoles.Where(x => x.Selected).Select(y => y.RoleName));
            var currentUser = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
            await _signInManager.RefreshSignInAsync(currentUser);
            await Data.Seeds.DefaultUsers.SeedSuperAdminAsync(_userManager, _roleManager);
            return RedirectToPage("/Admin/Index"); 
        }
    }
```

**Stack Trace**

```
System.InvalidOperationException: There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first.
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.<>c.<ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync>b__169_0(Task`1 result)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot, Thread threadPoolThread)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.InitializeReaderAsync(DbContext _, Boolean result, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.SingleOrDefaultAsync[TSource](IAsyncEnumerable`1 asyncEnumerable, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.SingleOrDefaultAsync[TSource](IAsyncEnumerable`1 asyncEnumerable, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserStore`9.IsInRoleAsync(TUser user, String normalizedRoleName, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1.IsInRoleAsync(TUser user, String role)
   at Navrae.WebApp.Pages.RoleManager.UserRolesModel.OnGetAsync(String userId) in C:\Users\Work Laptop\source\repos\Navrae\Navrae.WebApp\Pages\RoleManager\UserRoles.cshtml.cs:line 45
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.ExecutorFactory.NonGenericTaskHandlerMethod.Execute(Object receiver, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.InvokeHandlerMethodAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.InvokeNextPageFilterAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.Rethrow(PageHandlerExecutedContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy.AuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler.HandleAsync(RequestDelegate next, HttpContext context, AuthorizationPolicy policy, PolicyAuthorizationResult authorizeResult)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.MigrationsEndPointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Comment: Try changing `foreach (var role in _roleManager.Roles)` to `foreach (var role in _roleManager.Roles.ToList())`

Comment: I switched back to my local db and it works fine. Not sure if its a setting I have on the SQL server causing the issue.

Comment: For SQL Server you have to enable MARS - "Multiple Active Result Sets", google it and you should find how to configure your connection string to enable it.

Comment: I tested it with your suggestion and it worked. I don't know why. Maybe the MARS research will lead to the answer. Thanks @LasseV.Karlsen!

Comment: The different is that with `.ToList()` you consumed the `Roles` collection before moving on to the loop body, which meant that as far as the database connection was concerned, you were done with iterating Roles. Without it, you had an open result set against the database for the Roles collection, when you also tried to execute `IsInRoleAsync` which then also tried to obtain a result set.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Lasse V. Karlsen, use .ToList() to close the data reader. Some changes I have to introduce for this fix is mentioned below.

Include ToList()

```
var dbData = dbContext.Table.Where(x=>x.ID=x).ToList();  //Include .ToList()
```

Include dbContext.Update(model)

```
foreach(var data in dbData)
{
    //do work
    dbContext.Update(data); //Update model
    dbContext.SaveChanges(); //Save it now or later
}
dbContext?.Dispose(); //depends on your code structure.
```

Hope this helps. The MARS could also be an option, but I have not tried it as the ToList() solution solved my problem.